# Differential equation existence of a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

Why is the answer TRUE TRUE? 
For the second one it is trivial but for the first one how can we know there will be a unique solution? shouldn't y(x) be required to be lipshitz for that to be true?

[image]

Comment: If the $x$ domain $[a,b]$ is bounded away from zero then $f(x,y)=y/x^2$ is a Lipschitz function of $y$ with Lipschitz constant $1/(\min \{ a^2,b^2 \})$. So under this domain constraint, Picard-Lindelof applies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear differential equation with continuous coefficients on its domain. On all $[a,b]\subset(0,\infty)$ the coefficient function $\frac1{x^2}$ is bounded, has a maximum, which is the local Lipschitz constant.